# link between detection algorithm and the knowledge base in Knowrob

Tags: roboearth, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all , I am working on an Roboearth application like Amigo who use roboearth to download object models to do a task

I am working now on detection package that detect the requested Object .

I tried  **re_object_detector_gui** package that use the **re_kinect_object_detector** algorithm

BUT ,, this gui is manually by user choose or download the object model

1- How can i use the detect algorithm **re_kinect_object_detector** without this gui

by automatic detect the correspond object when i ask it for a cup for example
this query search on knowrob data set and the result model detected by the detection algorithm ?

2- **i wanna a sequence of how this process working**  **like** : first ,query from the user by ..
Second : search in the knowledge base using ...
third : if he found the model that match my request detect it by ...
etec ...

### thanks :)

### **Edited :**

I made a simple talker node that publish an object model path in the **re_kinect/model_path (std_msgs/String)**

see the code :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("re_kinect/model_path", 1000);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

  int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {

    std_msgs::String msg;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "/home/turtlebot/Desktop/drink.b5ero_kinect" << count;
    msg.data = ss.str();

    ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());
}

}
```

and rosmaked it with no error
then :

1- run the openni launch

2- run the talker node , it returns the string of the model path

3- run the re_kinect node detector to detect

but it returns :

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-HP-Compaq-tc4400-EY609EA-ABB:~$ rosrun re_kinect_object_detector re_kinect
[ WARN] [1361999828.637136682]: no model files loaded!
```

how can it load the fixed model path i have entered all the time i run the detector ?
where is the wrong ?

and that is the rxgraph for it :
[image: image description]

thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54110/link-between-detection-algorithm-and-the-knowledge-base-in-knowrob/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

re_kinect_object_detector publishes the detected objects on a topic, as described in the documentation: http://www.ros.org/wiki/re_kinect_object_detector

To get the object detections into KnowRob, you will need to write a topic listener that listens to all detected objects and creates the corresponding instances in the knowledge base. An example for the re_vision recognition component can be found in re_ontology/prolog/comp_re_vision.pl (re_vision_listener/1). There is currently no listener for the DetectionResult messages, but the only thing you need to do is to adapt the re_vision listener to the other message format.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-02-15**:
actually i am a beginner in that, but i opened th object_detector main code ,, i Understand that it writes four topics :
ros::Subscriber kinect_sub;
ros::Subscriber model_sub;
ros::Publisher features_pub;
ros::Publisher detected_objects_pub;

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-02-15**:
Should i write this listener topic in main code ? this example of comp_re_vision.pl file in the prolog folder is a module ,, should i do a module like it in re_kinect_object_detector ??

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-02-17**:
It seems that the concept of topics is not really clear, I recommend the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics. You probably want to create your own program that listens to the detected_objects topic.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-02-17**:
i have been read this tutorial before and did this turtlism app , but i didn't use it in a own code before . thanks moritz i 'll try :)

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-02-27**:
Question edited please check it :) thanks :)